# Is it possible to `lmap` a key to multiple characters?

Tags: key-bindings

I want to use `f` and `t` command for Unicode characters, so `lmap` is the way to go. I can map a letter to a Japanese kanji:

```
:lmap k 中
```

then after `i_CTRL-^`, I can press `fk` to locate `中`。

However, there is a problem. There are only 26 letters, so I have to map a single letter to multiple characters. Or it will be meaningless. Actually I hope to map the first letter of the English spelling to the underlying Kanji character.

Then how can I `lmap` a letter to multiple alternative characters?

Answer (score 1):

This direction may not work.

I just re-`nmap` all these `fa`, `fb`, ..., `fz` to function calls. And it works.